# Problems with deploy one several database projects by TFS Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, database-project

I have got two database projects in my solution:

1. Database - which contains schema and default data.
2. TestData - which references the first one and contain test data.

I need to configure TFS Build process to deploy only one of them depending to build definition (for example only Database). But currently TFS Build deploys both projects.

Could somebody help with it?

Comment: Your build process should not deploy anything. You should have a separate process that runs after a successful build that handles releasing your software.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by creating 2 different build configurations in the VS solution, where one configuration deploys only Database and the other configuration deploys only TestData. Try this:

1. In Visual Studio, Go to **Build** menu > **Configuration Manager...**
2. Create a new configuration by opening the **Active solution configuration** drop down list and selecting **<New...>**. Name it something like "Database Only".
3. Back in the Configuration Manager window, make sure your new configuration is selected, and make sure the **Deploy** checkbox is checked for only the Database project.
4. Repeat these steps to create another configuration for "TestData Only" where only the TestData has Deploy checked.
5. In TFS Build, select whichever configuration is appropriate.